# What is the schema for Show Fields MySQL resultset?

Tags: mysql

I find myself in a peculiar situation while building a query builder in .net of needing to know this information so I can setup the appropriate structured classes.

What is the schema information for

```
SHOW FIELDS FROM `foo`;
```

I have tried

```
SHOW FIELDS FROM (SHOW FIELDS FROM `foo`) tbl1
```

... however that yields a sql error

> [Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(SHOW FIELDS FROM foo) tbl1' at line 1

I need to know the information about the columns returned.   I could cheat and make them all strings, but I would much rather to use the ACTUAL structure (and if it truly is all strings, then damnnnnnnnn).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM tablename;
```

This will give you back structured information about fields.
More info on that:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/show-columns.html

For schema information you need to run:

```
DESCRIBE information_schema.columns
```

More about schema can be found here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-schema.html

Comment: If you read the question,   SHOW FIELDS (shown in example above), SHOW COLUMNS(does the same as show fields), and DESCRIBE(does the same as show fields),   I want the information about the columns THOSE commands return.   Aka, what is the schema for the columns :  Field, Type, Null, Key, Default, Extra ----   are they varchar......  text..... etc etc.   I would like the SQL command that returns this reult structure ON this result structure.

Comment: Oh, get it now. You are basically asking about MySQL system tables, about information schema (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-schema.html), right?

Comment: Command is a bit longer than that as it requires mapping the same way as  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/columns-table.html   is laid out.   But it does give the field information by going direct to the information_schema database.   It sucks cuz I can't think of a way to get this information via a straight up query in the Show / Describe format.